# Try to use Hotswap + NetBeans + Payara

Tags: netbeans-8, hibernate-4.x, hotswap, payara

I have a JEE7 app Payara 4.1.2.174 + JSF2 + RichFaces + PrimeFaces + JPA2 + Hibernate4 + JTA Connection Pool running fine without the Hotswap config.

I had configured my env using this tutorial http://blog.payara.fish/using-hotswapagent-to-speed-up-development?success=true to use HotSwap and had some problems:

1) HotSwap arises many exceptions about some plugins not found like Tomcat, Spring, Maven, etc, that I don't use in my project. Is there a way to disable checking of these plugins?

2) Is this plugin required? Other error is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hotswap/agent/config/PluginManager
GRAVE:   RAR8061: failed to load resource-adapter-config or RA [ __dm_jdbc_ra ], com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Failed to start resource adapter : org/hotswap/agent/config/PluginManager
```

3) I don't get to run the access to connection pool:

```
GRAVE:   RAR8060: Unable to lookup pool [ sitesat2-isPool ], javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/sitesat2-isPool' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pools]
GRAVE:   RAR6017 : Failed to get connection pool object sitesat2-is via JNDI lookup : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/sitesat2-isPool' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
```

4) I think PluginManager from 2) is needed to work 3) because this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hotswap/agent/config/PluginManager
...
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at util.MultiEntityManagerImpl.getDataSource(MultiEntityManagerImpl.java:56)
```

Is there some specific config to work some plugins, mainly the connection to databases + JPA + JTA + Hibernate?

**GRAVE**:   Application deployment failed: Exception while preparing the app

Comment: Have you copied `hotswap-agent.jar` into the `lib/ext` directory in the domain as instructed in the tutorial, in the section "Using HotswapAgent with Payara Server", step 1 ?  It seems that Hotswap Agent classes aren't on the classpath. This is necessary because adding the JAR as agent doesn't put its classes on the classpath and the agent doesn't know how to add it to Payara Server's classpath automatically.

Comment: Can you explain what's GRAVE? I think it's not related to Payara Server or Hotswap Agent, so it's confusing what it means.

Comment: hi @OndrejM Yes, hotswap-agent.jar is in the path /opt/lp/payara-4.1.2.174/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext/hotswap-agent.jar

Comment: This seems like HotswapAgent just breaks something inside Payara Server. HotswapAgent isn't fully tested with Payara and may break some features, especially after some code reloads. Often a restart of the server helps. If it doesn't, try raising an issue on Payara's github, but also understand that while the Payara team tries to improve developer experience, they don't have the capacity to provide support for all third-party tools like HotswapAgent.

Comment: hi @OndrejM these problems occur since first execution.of hotswap+payara. Then, this is not a problem "after some code reloads"